# How to set react native android repositories when duplicate jar

Tags: android, reactjs, native

I use react native android. 
I overwrite nineoldandroids for gesture use,I put the nineoldandroids as a android.library.The problem is when building the project，error

java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener.class

so,I want to kown where can set react native repositories .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgYIe.png)

I seach the project find this :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$projectDir/../../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

How it work?